# How to deep-copy a nested structure

Tags: javascript, deep-copy

I have a complicated structure shown bellow,

[image]

This structure is nested, but I need to deep-copy it. My copy function is

```
export function copy(o) {
   if(typeof o==='object' || Array.isArray(o)) return 
   JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o));
   return o;
}
```

When I use this function to copy the structure, the error shows,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at copy (util.jsx:50)
```

Any good ideas about how to copy nested structures? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You have functions and symbols there, you can't use JSON.stringify/parse

Comment: You're correct - in this case,JSON.stringify() won't work if the OP wants to retain the functions and/or symbols.  But in other cases, it can actually be the most efficient (and simplest!) way to "deep copy".  Q: Of the many alternatives in the "duplicate" you cited, which one would you recommend to the OP?

Comment: You shouldn't mark as a duplicate when the answer gives a jQuery solution, time for an update.